# preg_replace com Regex para acrescentar uma tag

Tags: php, string, regex

Alguém sabe como fazer para o `regex` selecionar a frase e acrescentar uma tag?

```
<li>
  <p>b) texto muito longo;</p>
</li>


$FechasemClassAlinea = '<p>[a-z])_.*</p>\n</li>$';

$FechacomClassAlinea = '<p>[a-z])_.*</p>\n</li>\n</ol>$';

echo preg_replace($FechasemClassAlinea, $FechacomClassAlinea, $documento);
```

Gostaria que retornasse este valor:

```
  <li>
    <p>b) texto muito longo;</p>
  </li>
</ol>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
preg_replace('/(<p>[a-z]\).*<\/p>\s*<\/li>)/', '$1'."\n</ol>", $documento);
```

Explicando:

Na função preg_replace o primeiro parâmetro é o regex que deve iniciar e terminar com barra / dentro do regex é preciso fazer o escape dos caracteres que tem um significado especial no regex como ) e / nesse caso, adicionando uma barra invertida antes do caracter, o \s representa caracteres de espaço/tab/nova linha etc, deve ser usado no lugar do \n que você colocou, por último colocamos tudo dentro de parênteses () para criar um grupo, pois essa parte deve continuar depois da substituição.

No segundo parâmetro colocamos o que vai substituir o texto selecionado no regex, nesse caso devemos manter o grupo selecionado no regex, para pegar um grupo devesse usar $ seguido do número do grupo em ordem crescente começando por 1, e no final concatenamos a tag que vai ser adicionada.

Comment: Valeu cara, funcionou!!!

Answer (score 0):

Consegui realizar o que pretendi com jquery

este é o código

```
$('p').filter(function(){return $(this).text().match(/^[a-z]\)\s/) }).parent().addClass( "alinea");
```