# Acrescentar a class ao resultado do Regex no preg_replace

Tags: php, regex

Gostaria de acrescentar a classe inciso com o regex e o preg_replace

```
echo preg_replace("/<li\>\s*<p\>[a-z]\)\s/", "/<li class=\"inciso\"\>\s*<p\>[a-z]\)\s/", $documento);
```

Este é o modelo das linhas do meu documento:

```
<li>
  <p>a) longo texto</p>
</li>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Me parece que você não compreendeu o funcionamento da função [preg_replace](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.preg-replace.php), pois você passou como segundo parâmetro uma expressão regular, quando deveria usar o texto que deve susbstituir o que foi encontrado.

Além disso vocês está escapando (com barra invertida) os caractere `>` que não tem função especial na expressão regular.

Para fazer seu código funcionar você deve usar uma *subpatern* (grupo delimitado com parênteses) e referências ($n onde n é um número):

```
preg_replace('/<li>(\s*<p>[a-z]\)\s)/', '<li class="inciso">$1', $documento);
```

A explicação dessa expressão regular pode ser encontrada [nessa resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/61114/#61118)

Comment: É Sanção, sei que ainda não entendi muito, Uma pergunta, este $1 é o resto da string encontrada? é isso.

Comment: $1 refere-se ao 1º grupo de parenteses da expressão regular

Answer (score 1):

Usar Regex com HTML [não é uma boa idéia](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/2099835).

Ao invés disso você pode usar o `DOM`:

```
<?php

$dom = new DomDocument;
$dom->loadHTML("<li><p>a) longo texto</p></li>");

$lis = $dom->getElementsByTagName('li');

foreach ($lis as $li) {

    $li->setAttribute('class', 'inciso');

}
```

Comment: Valeuuuuuuu, mas como fazer, se tenho várias linhas que mudam o indice,a), b), c), d) e assim por diante

Comment: `$img` dentro do `foreach` deveria ser `$li`

Comment: bem observado @Sanção, valeu

Comment: @AlêMoraes é possivel usar o XPath para isso.